# Sprecher's book "Elements of Real Analysis"

Tags: real-analysis, book-recommendation

While on Ebay, I happened to find this old book, "Elements of Real Analysis" by Sprecher:  https://books.google.com.au/books/about/Elements_of_Real_Analysis.html?id=9Ua2PVXK3HkC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&gboemv=1&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Anyone has experience with this book? The author says it is sort of introductory but the book seems to cover material that looks different than modern-day intro books like Abbott, Ross, or Bartles.

Any insights?

Thanks

Comment: No but he was a colleague a long time ago.

Comment: Is it a good book for self-study?

Comment: I never read it. Rudin’s blue book is the gold standard, but some of the writing is too hard for modern people.